# How do i make a Shape dynamically re-sizable in android?

Tags: android, shapes

I want to select a particular portion of the camera view. I am thinking of drawing a re-sizable rectangle/circle whose size can dynamically be change via touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override onDraw method

```
private void onDraw(Canvas c){

invalidate();
super.onDraw();

//detect position of two fingers touching screen to define the corners of your rectangle

//draw your rectangle
}
```